# Unkind flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454600/java-syntax-error-on-my-system-working-on-my-friends-system#comment93781721_53454600) as unkind because this to me looked to be the textbook example of newbie-biting (on top of being completely unnecessary in the first place, because another comment already asked for the same thing in a much nicer way). It even has caps aka shouting on the internet. Really curious to know why my flag was declined, so I can improve my future flagging behavior.

Comment: I'm fencing on Makoto here. Yet the capped text could have been normal but using bold instead for emphasis. So yeah, shouting doesn't help and we don't like it when OP's use caps neither and they're told about it that caps are considered as them yelling at us and probably get downvoted for it.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why the 'unkind' flag exists. It's safer just to use "No longer needed".

Comment: fwiw I don't like the comment. It sounds impatient and the caps locks is considered yelling.

Comment: as someone being called out *twice* for being 'unkind', i am really curious what this comment was, then, as it still has been deleted. (typiing in all lowercase just to make sure this one will not get flagged.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not unkind to ask for errors in a question.  That's all the commentator was doing.

Admittedly the tangent about the attorney and police was a bit...tangential, but there was nothing here that was unkind or mean.

Comment: This is probably because English isn't my first language, but doesn't "how about you do X" sound confrontational? And the all-caps demand for errors..

Comment: That's why I said that the tangent was tangential; it didn't really belong in the comment and it only served to confuse.  Reading more for context and intent rather than simply looking *at* the text, the context is simple:  the commentator wants to see an error message.

Comment: (Alternatively they shouldn't have commented and should have just voted to close for that *very* reason...)

Comment: Fair enough. My sensitivity was probably too high as a result of all the "be nice to newbies" posts from the SO team :)

Comment: @Vasan: It absolutely sounds confrontational. *Especially* when they start to go off with that analogy followed by the all caps. This is somebody clearly taking their exasperation out on the asker. We're supposed to sympathize with the exasperation but at the same time not condone taking it out on others like that.